# How to find a match on multiple columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Sheet1, I have two columns:

```
A       B 
Code    Model
---------------
A361B0  9839
A361B1  9831
```

In Sheet2, I have the same two columns but with many more rows. What I need to do is find cases where:

- "Code" in Sheet1 exists anywhere in "Code" on Sheet2
- "Model" in Sheet1 exists anywhere in "Model" on Sheet2
- "Code" AND "Model" combo in Sheet1 has a matching combo anywhere in Sheet2

Just so I am clear on the last point, both the code and the model on any single row in Sheet1 must be a match to both the code and the model on any single row in Sheet2. Does that make sense?

I have already figured out the first two

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2,Tracker!A:A,0),"Match"),"Not Found")
```

In the case of "Code" this returns "Match" if a match is found anywhere in the A column of Sheet2, and "Not Found" if no match is found in the A column of Sheet2. Easy enough to repeat for "Model".

But I am struggling to figure out the last one. I have tried googling this multiple ways but have not found en example that does what I want. And I've tried to modify this formula to compare two columns vs two columns, but I am just not getting there.

**EDIT:**

For example, where Column C in Sheet1 has a formula:

```
Sheet1
A        B        C
Code     Model    Result
A361B0   9839     Match     // found in row 3 of Sheet1
A361B1   9831     Not Found // not found in Sheet2

Sheet2
A        B
Code     Model
B361X1   87315
A361B0   9839
A361B1   9832
```

Comment: Can you show us what your expected outcome is?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, by "outcome" I'm not sure what you mean. It would either be "match" or "not found". Do you want a full example?

Comment: See edit with example. Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://www.contextures.com/excellookupmultiplecriteriaindexmatch.html#indexmatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet2!A:A=Sheet1!A2),--(Sheet2!B:B=Sheet1!B2))>0,"Match", "Not Found")
```

This will look to see if there is a row in Sheet 2 that matches the one in sheet 1 (i.e. both values are the same)

Comment: Thanks! I am getting a #REF error. Invalid cell ref error. Not sure why. Code is in A2. Model is in B2. Your formula is in cell C2.

Comment: Never mind. I know why. Hang on....

Comment: I changed the names of my sheets. Once I made them match in the formula, it worked. Thank you!